# Can every DFA be converted to an equivalent one that has a single accept state

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I know that it is true for NFAs. It seems similar.

Comment: try to build the DFA for `a(a?)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Myhill–Nerode theory implies the following result:

> Every DFA for a regular language has at least as many accepting states as the minimal DFA.

Indeed, suppose that the minimal DFA has $m$ accepting states. Let $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ be words which cause the minimal DFA to reach these states. Now consider any DFA for the same language, and let $q_1,\ldots,q_m$ be the states that the DFA reaches upon reading $w_1,\ldots,w_m$. Since $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ are in the language, all these states must be accepting. Furthermore, they must be different, since they are pairwise inequivalent (for each $i \neq j$ there exists a word $x$ such that $w_ix$ is in the language and $w_jx$ isn't, or vice versa). So the DFA contains at least $m$ accepting states.

It is not difficult to construct a regular language whose minimal DFA contains more than one accepting state - for example, the language of all words whose length is not divisible by 3. This language refutes your conjecture.

Comment: So, the class of all the languages that can be accepted by a DFA with a single accept state is a  proper subset of the regular languages. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion. A regular language $L$ can be accepted by a DFA with a single accepting state if for all $x,y \in L$ and all $z \in \Sigma^*$, $xz \in L$ iff $yz \in L$.

Comment: Is it just a sufficient condition?

Comment: Sufficient and necessary.

Comment: You can find out by computing the minimal DFA, which also has the minimum number of accepting states.